# Setting the properties of items in an customview in iOS

Tags: ios, custom-view, awakefromnib

I am creating a customView and for example, would like to set the text color of the label and initialise the text of the label.

The initWithFrame is the generic function.

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}
```

I have tried initialising the label in the initWithFrame, but it doesn't work. But when I do it in awakeFromNib, it allows me to set the text color but not the text(this value comes from a dictionary)

```
-(void)awakeFromNib
{
    //setting of the label textcolor
}
```

What would be the correct way to initialise the color and text of labels and other stuff?

Need some suggestions and guidance...

Edit:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
   [self updateViewWithDictionary:dictPassed];
}
```

Something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I do in some project's is expose a public method like so:

```
- (void)updateViewWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)confDictionary;
```

In that dictionary I pass the parameters I want, and inside the `UIView's` subview I update it according to what I want.

**Edit 1:**

Read wrongly your question, sorry. You have a custom `UIView` that you would like to be updated when your `UIViewController` starts, or when you actually use it. So you should have something like this:

```
@interface MyView : UIView
{

}

- (void)updateViewWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)confDictionary;

@end
```

And from your `viewDidLoad`:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
   [self.customView updateViewWithDictionary:dictPassed];
}
```

Comment: UIView's subview -> can explain a little bit more on this.. Would be nice if you could share an example...

Comment: `@interface MyLabelSuperAwesome : UILabel`. So `UILabel` inherit from the `UIView` maybe I should have said `UILabel's` subview.

Comment: i mean where do u call it? inside what function?

Comment: Once you put your `UILabel's` subview in place, you can call that method. Or, if you are using it from a Nib, you call the method from `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: @lakesh do you understand now?